# mod rewrite url with question mark

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to convert a URL that looks like this to

`card.php?type=blacksmith&style=new&card=fighter&rotation=270`

to

`images/card/backsmith/new/fighter.jpg?270`

I have a mod rewrite that works if I make the `?` mark a slash, but I would much rather prefer it to be a `?` instead of a slash.

EDIT
Forgot to include my current mod rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^images/cards/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*).jpg?([^/]*)$ card.php?type=$1&style=$2&card=$3&rotation=$4
```

Comment: You need to escape the `?` with a backslash `\?`. Also, it's not clear if you're trying to convert from or to the short format. You say you want to convert to the short format, but your code shows the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string using `RewriteRule`.

Use this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^images/cards/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.jpg$ card.php?type=$1&style=$2&card=$3&rotation=%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Did not know that. Thanks, this has been driving me crazy for the past 24 hours.

Comment: Whoops, thought I did do that.